# why no NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException in this example?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I think the following program will throw NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException but in fact it will not, but why?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class TestController extends BaseController<IAnimal>{

    public TestController() {
        System.out.println("TestController constructor");
    }
    \\......
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseController<A> {
     @Inject protected A animal;
```

```
public class Cat implements IAnimal {
```

```
public class Dog implements IAnimal {
```

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration  implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean public IAnimal Cat() throws Exception { return new Cat(); }
    @Bean public IAnimal Dog() throws Exception { return new Dog(); }
```

after the server is startup, I find TestController constructor is run,

1. but why

```
     @Inject protected A animal;
```

does not throw NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException? As there are two bean both implement the IAnimal interface. (A is IAnimal in TestController class)

2. I see there are @Qualifer or @Named annotation to distinguish which implement to inject, then in above case, if I want TestController inject Cat, how should I do?

added:
3) I found after server startup, animal in object testController is null, why? why TestContrller is created (constructor has run) but its field animal has not been injected?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where/when are you seeing it as `null`? (I don't think Spring can resolve this generic dependency. When it sees your `A` type, I think it will search for a bean of type `Object`. I don't think it tries to resolve what type argument you provided elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why @Inject is not worked because I use tomcat to test, tomcat is a servelet container and can not recognize @Inject, if I use WildFly application server then
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException is thrown.

```
 @Inject protected A animal;
```

If I change @Inject to @Autowired, then both tomcat or wildfly will throw NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException for the above program